# Dataflow IO to BigTable [2.9.0]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, apache-beam-io

I found this `Bigtable with Dataflow` example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/HelloWorldWrite.java

However; it uses

> beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java 2.4.0

and in 2.9.0 org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions is no longer there.

Is there an up to date example of writing to BigTable from Dataflow?

I found: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.html - is that on the right track?

Comment: Why not modify the example to support the latest SDK? In the process you will learn a few good details about how to write Dataflow programs. The changes required are minor.

Comment: I'll update the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the BigTable connector [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/HelloWorldWrite.java) you link to, following the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples), with Dataflow Java SDK 2.9.0 and it works fine. The only extra step needed is to change the SDK in the pom.xml file ([line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/pom.xml#L49)):

Replace `<beam.version>2.4.0</beam.version>` for `<beam.version>2.9.0</beam.version>`.

The Dataflow job will start (you'll see `Dataflow SDK version: 2.9.0` in std output). Once it succeeds you can verify in the HBase shell that the correct rows were written:

```
hbase(main):001:0> scan 'Dataflow_test'
ROW                                                                              COLUMN+CELL
 Hello                                                                           column=cf:qualifier, timestamp=1548151071821, value=value_21.60451762361535
 World                                                                           column=cf:qualifier, timestamp=1548151064955, value=value_21.60451762361535
2 row(s) in 1.4230 seconds
```

Comment: Oh; I must have typo'd something and got myself a touch confused thereafter
Will work through again.
Thanks